# Multiple lists and multiple file types in bash

Tags: bash, list, nested-loops, nested-lists

### The problem

There is a data processing problem where a sequence of actions are taken on different files. However, within the processing, different classes of files require specialization. The processing steps are long and cumbersome, and the goal is to *create and maintain a single loop.* My attempts tried to compose a master list of sublists which is keyed to specific actions of the elements in the list.

### Schematic example

A minimal version of the problem follows. The file classes can be marked by suffix.

#### Representative input data

```
export suffix=".png .svg"
export foo="a b c"
export bar="alpha beta chi"
```

#### Desired actions

In pseudo code

```
loop over master list
    first sublist foo
        create file names: a.png b.png c.png
    second sublist bar
        create file names: alpha.svg beta.svg chi.svg
```

#### Extra credit

Nested counters would be great as the lists are long. E.g. `chi.svg` would be step 2.3

Comment: That looks like python.

Comment: Include a [mcve].

Comment: @oguz ismail: If I could do that, there would be no need for the question.

Comment: See [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) then, this is too broad for [so].

Answer (score 1):

Use nameref, `eval` or indirection to simulate a nested array.

1. nameref:

```sh
foo=(a b c)
bar=(alpha beta chi)

arrays=(foo bar)
suffix=(.png .svg)

declare -n arr
let i=0
for arr in "${arrays[@]}"; do
    for elem in "${arr[@]}"; do
        echo "${elem}${suffix[i]}" 
    done
    let i++
done
```

This declares `arr` as a nameref. When you operate `arr`, you are actually operating the variable specified by the value of `arr`.

You can add a counter for the inner loop with `let j=0` and `let j++`, or do the following:

```
for (( i = 0; i < ${#arrays[@]}; i++ )); do
    declare -n arr="${arrays[i]}"
    for (( j = 0; j < ${#arr[@]}; j++ )); do
        echo "${arr[j]}${suffix[i]}"
    done
done
```

2. `eval`:

```sh
foo=(a b c)
bar=(alpha beta chi)

suffix=(.png .svg)
arrays=(foo bar)

for (( i = 0; i < ${#arrays[@]}; i++ )); do
    eval "arr=( \${${arrays[i]}[@]} )"
    for (( j = 0; j < ${#arr[@]}; j++ )); do
        echo "${arr[j]}${suffix[i]}"
    done
done
```

This evaluates string `arr=( \${foo[@]} )`, which creates an array `arr` with the elements of `foo`.

3. indirection:

```sh
foo=(a b c)
bar=(alpha beta gama)

arrays=('foo[@]' 'bar[@]')
suffix=(.png .svg)

let i=0
for arr in "${arrays[@]}"; do
    for elem in "${!arr}"; do
        echo ${elem}${suffix[i]}
    done
    let i++
done
```

The `"${!arr}"` refers to the array `foo` or `bar`, but we can't index it or get the length of it (or is there something I missed?). Thus we can't use `for (( j = 0; ... ))` here.

Search [Bash reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) for the relevant documentation of nameref, `eval` and indirection.

Comment: Outstanding answer and superb explanation. Comparing different options makes this answer a terrific resource for the community.